# Docker on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have an application which needs Docker and the application checks for Docker daemon when it starts. I can not get away with this as it is a third party application.

So, getting error when i tried to deploy this app on Kubernetes.

```
Failed to run 'docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock ps -a': exited with status 1; stderr='Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I am not sure if Kubernetes is internally using Docker daemon for spinning up containers. Is there any way to get around with this?

Comment: Could you share more information with us? Its your local machine or On-Prem? Its minikube, kubeadm, microk8s? What OS are you using, what docker, kubernetes version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes can run without docker, but the app you're running requires to connect to docker. Could you try to run it with docker desktop running?

Comment: The app is running in my local as I am running docker on my local.

Comment: Hello Charlotte, welcome to StackOverflow. You will needs a bit more description. some ideas:
- mention what you are trying to achieve overall. When you make statements like "Kubernetes can run without docker" then please have a reference link with it. AFAIK kubernetes needs to have one or the other kind of containerization supported tool to work. The tool can be remote that's a possibility, if not local

Answer (score 0):

kubernetes by default uses docker also as a container runtime, so this means you need a docker within docker. it is possible generally, but needs some extra configuration and privileges. start with [this official docker blog article](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/) which should give you some pointers how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the docker socket file in your deployment.

```
docker container run -d \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock <image-name>
```

Similar changes can be added to Kubernetes deployment too.

Now, your application can connect with the docker daemon running in your local system.

However, it is not a good practice as it compromises the security isolations provided by docker.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to run Docker in the Kubernetes application.

### DOOD

Docker Out Of Docker. Here you have to mount host's /var/run/docker.sock on your container. It'll connect to the host's Daemon through it. But it is more vulnerable.

### DIND

Docker IN Docker. It is a container that runs both Docker Daemon and Docker cli by itself. Here we don't need to mount /var/run/docker.sock into the container. More secure than DOOD.